# PowerShell Script for Filtering in Excel

Tags: powershell

I am writing a code to filter out the second column (B) of my Excel sheet which consists of the side indicators. I am trying to filter and display the indicator `= >` only along with the corresponding column A data. However, whenever I run the code below I get the error

> Unable to get the Autofilter Property of the Range class
>   At line:14 char:1

CSV file format

```
Name SideIndicator
asdf   = >
asdf   = >
trew   = =
```

As I am pretty new to Excel automation using PowerShell, I am kind of stuck on where I am going wrong.

The code:

```
$file1 = "C:\Users\achowdhury\Desktop\Comparedfile.csv" # source's fullpath
$xl = New-Object -c Excel.Application
$xl.DisplayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user
$wb1 = $xl.Workbooks.Open($file1) # open target
$sh1 = $wb1.Sheets.Item('Comparedfile') # sheet in workbook
$sh1.Select()   
$sh1.Range("B1").Select() 
$xlFilterValues = 7 # found in MS documentation
$filterList = @("= >")

$rng = $sh1.Cells.Item(2).EntireColumn # selecting the entire column for filtering
$rng.Select | Out-Null

$xl.Selection.AutoFilter($sh1, $filterList, $xlFilterValues)

$wb1.Close($true) # close and save workbook
$xl.Quit()
```

Comment: Have you tried to convert your `Comparedfile.csv` into a `Comparedfile.xls` (or`.xlsx`) format to check if it's not a formatting issue? Not sure `csv` accepts any filtering option.

Comment: Hi Manu; I changed the file format to XLSX but I get the same error :(

Unable to get the Autofilter Property of the Range class
At line:14 char:1

Comment: Can you post a sample of your csv?

Comment: CSV Sample

Name       SideIndicator
==================================
D78654             ==
DUA410             ==
D011657             = >
DUA100            < =

Comment: Avik, you should add it to your question as it's not well formatted in comments.

Comment: I have typed in the sample CSV in the Question above.

Answer (score 0):

so if I get you right you have got a CSV file like this:

```
"left","direction","right"
"asdf","= >","qwert"
"asdf","= >","qwert"
"qwert","< =","asdf"
"asdf","= >","qwert"
```

You only want the lines where the column `direction` is equal to `= >`. For this you don't need Excel.

```
$file1 = "C:\Users\achowdhury\Desktop\Comparedfile.csv" # source's fullpath
$filtered = Import-Csv -Path $file1 | where {$_.direction -eq "= >"}
```

Now you have those lines in the variable `$filtered` which you could now export into another CSV file like so:

```
$file2 = "C:\Users\achowdhury\Desktop\Filteredcomparedfile.csv"
$filtered | Export-Csv -Path $file2 -NoTypeInformation
```

Or if you just want to output the value of the first column (which in my example is named `left` and the `direction` column:

```
$filtered | % { $output = $_.left, $_.direction -join " "; Write-Output $output;}
```

KR
Guenther

Comment: Thank you for the response. Here I am trying to put a filter because thereafter I have to generate a Pivot Table for the filtered Data. And the CSV that I have is in the following format:-

"name","side indicator"
"asdf",      "= >"
"asdf",      "= >",

So when I run the code base :-
$file1 = "C:\Users\achowdhury\Desktop\testcompfile.xlsx" # source's fullpath
$filtered = Import-Csv -Path $file1 | where {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="}
$file2 = "C:\Users\achowdhury\Desktop\Filteredcomparedfile.csv"
$filtered | Export-Csv -Path $file2 -NoTypeInformation 

the new file comes up blank.

Comment: `$filtered = Import-Csv -Path $file1 | where {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="}` must read `$filtered = Import-Csv -Path $file1 | where {$_."Side Indicator" -eq "=="}` if there is a space in the header or `$filtered = Import-Csv -Path $file1 | where {$_.SideIndicator -eq "= ="}` if there is a space in the equal sign.